# How to evaluate $ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{y^2\sin^2x}{x^4+y^4} $

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{y^2\sin^2x}{x^4+y^4}
$$

I believe the limit doesn't exist but I'm not sure how to prove/evaluate correctly. A hint would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{{{y^2}{x^2}}}{{{x^4} + {y^4}}}{\left( {\frac{{\sin x}}{x}} \right)^2}$$

Then choose $y=\alpha x$ and see what happens. Of course, use $$\frac{\sin x}x\to 1$$

Comment: Ok, I did that. I notice that the limit is dependent on the value of alpha which means the limit does not exist. Is this sufficient? Once I state this, what is the point of using sin(x)/x -> 1?

Comment: @flapjackery The point is that working with $\sin x$ is kind of annoying and tricky compared to polynomials, and separating out that limit lets you get rid of it, making the analysis easier.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. That makes sense. So to my earlier point, is it sufficient to say that since the limit depends on the value of alpha, the limit cannot exist?

Comment: @flapjackery Sure. That's the point of introducing $\alpha$ =)